# Rails 4: Order by association of association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models: `ProductsColor` which `belongs_to :product` and `Translation` which `belongs_to :product` as well.

In other words, Product `has_many :products_colors` and `has_many :translations`.

the Translation model has a field called `name`. How would I find all `ProductsColor` records and order them by the associated product's translations' names?

```
ProductsColor.includes(:product, :color).order(???)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Product.includes(:translations, :products_colors).order("product_translations.name ASC").map(&:products_colors)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ProductsColor.joins(product: :translations).order("translations.name ASC")
```

to get an ActiveRecord:Relation object (in case if you want to query on it)